# How to use Chart.js with Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, charts

In an Ionic-React app how to draw charts on any particular page using chart.js.

In fact, this is something that made me struggle a lot so I thought to post the question along with the answer so that anyone else can also use it.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

React is the framework added by Ionic recently. You may refer following code to display the chart on any particular page.

**1. Very first thing you need to install the react-chartjs**

```
npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js
```

**2. Ensure you've basic imports related to UI and Framework**

```
import { IonAvatar, IonButton, IonButtons, IonCard, IonCardContent, 
IonCardHeader, IonCardSubtitle, IonCardTitle, IonContent, IonFab, 
IonFabButton, IonFabList, IonHeader, IonIcon, IonItem, IonItemOption, 
IonItemOptions, IonItemSliding, IonLabel, IonList, IonListHeader, 
IonMenuButton, IonPage, IonText, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Dashboard.css';
import {addCircle, arrowBackCircle, key, add, addCircleOutline, timeOutline, folderOpen, calendarOutline, cardOutline} from 'ionicons/icons'
```

**3. Imports related to Chart**

```
import { Line, Bar, Pie , Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

**4. UI Code/ Logic**

```
const Dashboard: React.FC = (props) => {

//Set Data for Bar Chart. In Realtime you may bing this using the data coming from API or service. 
const barChartData = {
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
datasets: [
  {
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }
]
};

//Set Data for Doughnut Chart. In Realtime you may bing this using the data coming from API or service. 
const doughnutChartData = {
labels: ['Billable', 'Non Billable'],
datasets: [
  {
    label: 'Billable Vs. Non Billable',
    backgroundColor: ['#36a2eb', 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)'],
    borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    data: [65, 59]
  }
]
};


return (
<IonPage>
     <IonHeader>
            <IonToolbar  color="secondary">
                <IonButtons slot="start">
                    <IonMenuButton />
                </IonButtons>
                <IonTitle>Dashboard</IonTitle>
            </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
  <IonContent class="ion-padding">
   
        <IonList>
          <IonItem>
            //Bind the Bar Chart with the Data
            <Bar data={barChartData}
                options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true}}   />
          </IonItem>
          <IonItem>
            <Doughnut data={doughnutChartData}
                options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true}}   />
          </IonItem>
          <IonItem>
            <Pie data={doughnutChartData}
                options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true}}   />
          </IonItem>
        </IonList>

  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
);
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Above didn't work for me, I had to add these linesimport {CategoryScale} from 'chart.js'; 
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
Chart.register(CategoryScale);